# Plotting LiDAR's measured distance: fix the curvature caused by the angle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, curvature

I am trying to plot the distance measured with a LiDAR.
The angle range of the LiDAR is $90^\circ$, and I guess that is the cause of the curvature.
I was trying to convert the angles to radians but I didn't get any satisfactory results.

This is the plot I get at the moment while reading a flat surface.
Any idea how I could fix the curvature?

[image]

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Maybe you’re dealing with something like $d(\theta) = 400  \text{ ft }/ \cos\theta$ where $\theta$ is the offset angle in radians from the midpoint at $\pi / 4$. Just eyeballing. You might check it out and use it as a basis for what you actually need.